# Range data for string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to find a date in a column that is within this range:

```
date: 01-01-2018..08-01-2018
```

I tried this migration:

```
class AddColumnDataInHomeTask < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :home_tasks, :date, :string
  end
end
```

No error is raised, but it does not work. There is a problem with the type:

```
:string
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you store the `date` as a `date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll have to store the dates as the date type, not a string, in order to perform the kind of "between/range" query as you've described.

```
class AddColumnDataInHomeTask < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :home_tasks, :date, :date
  end
end
```

Then, consider this query:

```rb
records = HomeTask.where(:date => start_date..end_date)
```